# $f(x)=16\cos^2(3x)\cos^2(6x)\cos^2(12x)\cos^2(24x)$, what is the value of $f(\frac{\pi}{36})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $f(x)=16\cos^2(3x)\cos^2(6x)\cos^2(12x)\cos^2(24x)$, what is the
> value of $f(\frac{\pi}{36})$ ?
>
> $1)\frac{6-3\sqrt3}{16}\qquad\qquad2)\frac{6-\sqrt3}{16}\qquad\qquad3)\frac{6+\sqrt3}{16}\qquad\qquad4)\frac{6+3\sqrt3}{16}$

I'm looking for alternative approaches to solve this problem.
Here is my approach:

$$f(\frac{\pi}{36})=16\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{12})\cos^2(\frac{\pi}6)\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos^2(\frac{2\pi}{3})=\frac34\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{12})=\frac38(1+\cos(\frac{\pi}6))=\frac{6+3\sqrt3}{16}$$
I'm looking for other ideas to solve the problem, so can you please solve it differently?

Comment: [This](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxL06jQtDU009JQSM4v1jDWqtBU0AIzzUBMKNvQCCIO5hiZgDiacUZcaRoFmfrGZpp6xZm5BTmZaZXxJUWZ6RqaAJJeFuI=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) is indeed a different way to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can simplify $f(x)$ by using the identity $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$ multiple times.

$f(x)=\dfrac{16\sin^2(3x)\cos^2(3x)\cos^2(6x)\cos^2(12x)\cos^2(24x)}{\sin^2(3x)}=\dfrac{\sin^2 48x}{16\sin^2 3x}=\dfrac{\sin^2 48x}{8(1-\cos 6x)}$

$f(\frac{\pi}{36})=\dfrac{2\sin^2\frac{4\pi}{3}}{1-\cos \frac{\pi}{6}}=\dfrac{ \frac{3}{4}}{8(1-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})}=\dfrac{6+3\sqrt3}{16}$